# How to calculate average value based on range of data

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to calculate an average value based on corresponding values which fall into a certain criteria.I have setup a online sheet to illustrate the case, hopefully you can help me to get this working

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q_GQW90e0Q4KaJnvaekh8OGI1Km0Rs1uS8JKsOCqqK4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C1 cell write formula as below:

`=averageifs(available_data!C:C, available_data!C:C, ">"&$A3 - 0.5, available_data!C:C, "<"&$A3 + 0.5)`